# Cannot see Cache level data movement in Gem5 simulations

Tags: gem5

I am using the following CLI:

M5_PATH=/home/febin/Storage/Gem5/gem5ist/m5/system/ Gem5/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=Cache,Exec,DRAM,TLB Gem5/gem5/configs/example/fs.py --kernel x86_64-vmlinux-2.6.22.9 --num-cpus=64 --num-dirs=64 --caches --elastic-trace-en --num-l2caches=16 --ruby --network=garnet2.0 --topology=Mesh_XY --mesh-rows=8 --command-line="paper3/Blackscholes/blackscholes.out 1 paper3/Blackscholes/in_16.txt  paper3/Blackscholes/output.txt" >> paper3/Gem5_fs

I am able to see Exec, DRAM and TLB traces; but I cannot see any data from Cache. Same for SE simulations why is this ?

Comment: The "Cache" flag is within the classic caches, and the "RubyCache" flag is for Ruby caches (which is the one you are using: --ruby). Therefore you just need to switch to the proper flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel, you have to use `--debug-flags RubyCache` for ruby.

The flag is different because Ruby models the caches itself separately from the classic system.

Comment: one can use --caches in Atomic mode. Check my comment on Febin's question.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho thanks for the correction, I've edited my completely wrong answer. Next time I answer wrong, feel free to answer yourself and leave a comment so you can get credited more clearly, I would just have deleted my answer in that case.